# Count of all Text Occurrence within a File

Tags: find-occurrences

I have a file content of text lines (e.g 9 lines below):

```
111  
AAA  
AAA  
EEEE  
EEEE  
EEEE  
EEEE  
ZZZ1
```

How can I get the occurrence result of the text line as following using PS?

```
EEEE 4  
AAA  2  
111  1  
ZZZ1 1
```

Comment: PS?  PowerShell?  If so tag your question with that.  Also what have you tried and does not work?